# Phone only boots into twrp

Tags: samsung, twrp

I Have samsung note 20, after flashing twrp and vbmeta file  my phone only boots into twrp. have tried the key combinations but with no help. how do i restore it to stock firmware when it only boots to twrp?
Please help